# composite grammars: accessing imported grammars scope's in action

Tags: antlr, antlr3

Let's suppose I have two grammars (and that there is a Lexer defined somewhere), ParserA and ParserB.

In ParserA I have the following code:

```
parser grammar ParserA;

classDeclaration
scope {
    ST mList;
}
...
```

ParserB is something like:

```
parser grammar ParserB;

import ParserA;

methodDeclaration : something something { $classDeclaration::mList.add(...) };
```

The code in the action will fail to compile (by javac) since classDeclaration is in a different class (and file). Any tips on how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any tips on how to fix it?

No, there's (AFAIK) no ANTLR shortcut here: there's no communication possible between imported grammars (either by using scopes or by providing parameters to imported grammar rules).